# Prevent Alt+Tab from switching to minimized windows

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab

I have looked at various solutions to this but none worked.

How can I prevent <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows 10 from switching to minimized windows?

Answer (score 10):

The solution is to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

It'll switch to the next open window, skipping minimized ones. More importantly it works even if the Windows Shell hangs up and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> stops working

> Unfortunately, with all this excitement attached to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, another hotkey has been woefully neglected. Windows 2.0 introduced the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> hotkey. Whereas <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> lets you pick an application, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> lets you cycle through them.
>
> When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, the active window is sent to the bottom of the window stack, allowing the window beneath it in the z-order to become the new active window. And if the next window is a minimized window, it stays minimized. While this may sound like an annoyance, it is actually a useful device, as it lets you skip past minimized applications without having to open them.
>
> [Raymond Chen Discusses the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> Hotkeys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd424927(v=msdn.10))

Comment: the issue is I can't toggle between two windows with Alt+Esc

Comment: Yeah, I'd forgotten about Alt-Esc, I tend to use Alt-Tab and Alt-Shift-Tab to move back/forth, age-old habit.    This sequence works for me between two windows (unfortunately regardless of minimize status).

Comment: @kofifus you can use Alt+Esc and Alt+Shift+Esc to toggle back and forth. Otherwise you'll need an autohotkey script

Comment: I'd really rather have the alt-tab work properly between open windows, and alt-esc to do the swapping of all running programs.   Alt-esc is a rather more obcure and uncomfortable combo, and besides; why the hell to change the alt-tab behaviour?

Comment: @SteveHorvath it has never been changed and is almost globally used to switch between applications. Only Alt+Esc is new with a different behavior

Comment: @phuclv I hear you but this isn't how it was working on win7 - so it must have changed, then, no?  Anyway, it matters little, what microsoft does usually remains unchangeable, anyway.

Comment: @SteveHorvath no it's still the same in Windows 7 and 10. Nothing has been changed

Comment: Alt-Esc doesn't switch back to my most recently viewed window; it's unclear to me what order it is cycling in.  Not a substitute for Alt-Tab imo.
I also concur with @SteveHorvath that Windows used to send minimized Windows to the back of the queue, if not by default, at least there was a setting to make it do so. Am I hallucinating?

Comment: Interesting, it looks like Alt-Esc actually sends the window you just left to the back of its queue, rather than demoting it to the first non-current entry (but leaves the Alt-Tab queue as you would expect).  I guess it's effectively minimizing the window you leave?  Odd behavior to me. But maybe there's a way to use this in combo with Alt-Tab (i.e. use Alt-Esc if you want to avoid minimized Windows, Alt-Tab if not)?
  
At this point I'd rather have Alt-Tab work as described.

Answer (score 4):

The following script for AutoHotkey v1.1 fixes this issue by detecting when any window is minimized, and forcing it toward the end of the alt-tab list by temporarily changing window styles. The script runs in the background and does not require using a specific hotkey (or any hotkey).

```
; Use a shell hook to detect minimize and fix the alt-tab order.
OnMessage(DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", "str", "SHELLHOOK"), "ShellHook")
DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", "ptr", A_ScriptHwnd)

ShellHook(wParam, lParam)
{
    if (wParam != 0x5) ; HSHELL_GETMINRECT
        return
    hwnd := NumGet(lParam+0)
    WinGet minmax, MinMax, ahk_id %hwnd%
    if (minmax = -1) ; Minimized
    {
        ; Remove the window from the alt-tab list temporarily to force
        ; it to the end of the list.  To do this, temporarily apply the
        ; WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style and remove WS_EX_APPWINDOW (if present).
        WinGet oldxs, ExStyle, ahk_id %hwnd%
        newxs := (oldxs & ~0x40000) | 0x80
        if (newxs != oldxs)
        {
            WinSet ExStyle, % newxs, ahk_id %hwnd%
            WinSet ExStyle, % oldxs, ahk_id %hwnd%
        }
    }
}
```

Caveat: This may have adverse effects on some windows since it modifies the window's extended style attribute (temporarily). I did not observe any issues during my testing.

I found that temporarily removing the window from alt-tab moved it *almost* to the end of the list. If I minimize multiple windows in a row, the first one appears last, with each subsequent minimized window inserted before the others (but after all other windows).

I tested on Windows 10 v1709. Results may vary on other systems.

Comment: Great ! Can I hook this to replace the existing Alt+Tab ? how ?

Comment: It does not "replace Alt+Tab". It manipulates windows, as I explained. You just run the script using AutoHotkey v1.1. Basically, install AutoHotkey, save the script text as a file with `.ahk` extension, open the file. If it works, add it to system startup via whatever method.

Answer (score 2):

I use a second "Virtual Desktop" for this type of stuff, it works really well.
You can move the apps/windows to the secondary/tertiary/... desktop, and that desktop will only have that subset of tabs (I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> constantly, so I'm fairly keyed into your "problem").

Drag-drop works for moving the apps quickly, and there are other shortcuts and managers, if you want to have more semi-permanent virtual desktops for a certain task(s).

Comment: thx but this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: This was the best answer. Often with Microsoft products, if something doesn't have a desired option/capability, then this means that (philosophically) Microsoft is telling you that there is a better way. For example, if one has five windows but only wants to work with two of them, then that's exactly a scenario for putting the two windows on a separate workspace (desktop). This is fast and easy to do, simply use Windows-Tab and drag the two windows to a new desktop. Then Alt-Tab or Alt-Esc will only see the two widows that you are working with. That's what the philosophy of a workspace is.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what @LưuVĩnhPhúc suggested, and I went ahead and wrote a short [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that does more or less that.

### The Script

```
forward := true
cycling := false

~Alt Up::
if cycling
    forward := !forward
cycling := false
return

!Tab::Cycle(forward)
!+Tab::Cycle(!forward)

Cycle(direction)
{
    global cycling
    if direction
    {
        send !{Escape}
    }
    else
    {
        send !+{Escape}
    }
    cycling := true
}

!Escape::!Tab
```

Install the program, put this in an `.ahk` file somewhere and run it.
It will set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> alternatingly so you can switch back and forth. The last line makes it so that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> functions as the regular <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, in case you want to still have access to that functionality. You can remove it if you want.

### Caveats

1. This script changes <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to be either <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd>, changing its direction whenever you release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key after having switched windows (i.e. also pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>) at least once.

   This doesn't change the mechanism behind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd>, so if you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, you may not get to the second-before-last window you were in. Also when the direction is "reversed" you may get "older" windows (windows you haven't used in a while) before you get recent ones, with the exception of the last window you switched to; you'll get that one (that's the whole reason I made that flip in direction in the first place).
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> still retains its original function - i.e. it uses the regular <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> mechanism. No idea what you want to do about that.

### More Complicated Alternative

Another option is to write a program that can hide all the currently minimized windows and restore them, then use AutoHotkey to make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> activate that program to hide all the minimized windows before letting the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> through, and then have it show them again when you release <kbd>Alt</kbd> after having switched windows (no need to do it if you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> for other reasons).

This requires more work, however, and it'll result in your open applications in the taskbar changing while you switch windows and reverting when you stop, which may look strange.

If you choose to do this, I suggest you take notice not to invoke the program simply on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but only on the first time you press that combination since you've held down <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: thx ! but switching back and forth between windows using two consequtive alt+tab is essential for me. Is it possible to write a script that covers that as well ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I wrote this script to do just that. Try it out, see for yourself.